# Drupal makes empty $_SESSION variable from external page

Tags: php, session, drupal, drupal-7

I have custom login form on drupal site. Form send ajax to other application (non-drupal). This app writes data to `$_SESSION` and return `"success"` to drupal site. But in Drupal I have empty `$_SESSION`.

I think trouble in `session.inc` because drupal sets own session storage functions, but I can't find where disapper my `$_SESSION` value. I know that there is data in `$_SESSION` because when do 
`session_start(); 
print_r($_SESSION);`

in drupal `index.php` file, I see full `$_SESSION` array.

Have someone any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want , your user auth is external and don't have an account into drupal database ?

Comment: I'm using drupal authorization, but I also have another project with it's own internal user auth logic and I just need to get $_SESSION with data from this script to use in drupal in few custom functions

Comment: i think you should add data to response into your external service and when drupal get it , store it into his session

Comment: i can't  make any changes in external system, only can use $_SESSION variable, but drupal make it empty

Comment: Yes, Drupal does that - I faced it my self. What I did is switched to cookies. Can you do that too? Use cookies instead of session?

Comment: no, custom information, that i need, writes only in session. Can i some how catch $_SESSION before drupal reset it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can bootstrap Drupal inside your code, and write the session once Drupal is bootstrapped. That will write the SESSION data to the database and allow you to continue to Drupal without problems.

But it's not logical to me that Drupal doesn't count your SESSION data once your user returns... as the code which starts the session reads SESSION before starting it.

Is it possible that Drupal and your external app are handling different session IDs?

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_start/7.x

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, reason really in session id. Drupal generate random session id `session_id(drupal_random_key());`  in `drupal_session_initialize()`